# what's the difference between Homebrew's sevenzip and p7zip formulae?

Tags: homebrew

I want to install 7zip. Homebrew appears to have two different formulae for this.

```
brew install sevenzip
```

```
brew install p7zip
```

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/sevenzip

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/p7zip

Following the links to their respective home pages the both claim to be the latest with fairly recent releases. Is one of these projects an imposter? What's the difference? Which one do I want to install?

Comment: Just FYI - The command to use with sevenzip is 7zz, and not 7z. Hope this helps someone who wanders into this page!

Answer (score 4):

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/p7zip refers to https://github.com/jinfeihan57/p7zip. From the "About" box there:

> A new p7zip fork with additional codecs and improvements (forked from https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/)

The sourceforge repository claims to be "a quick port of 7z.exe and 7za.exe (command line version of 7zip, see [www.7-zip.org](http://www.7-zip.org)) for Unix." And 7-zip.org is where (according to the formula) `sevenzip` comes from.

So `p7zip` seems to be a fork of `sevenzip` with "additional codecs and improvements".